# Grouping Array element using two properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, group-by

I am attempting to group an array elements ( containing orders details ).
here is my array structure :

[image]

```
[{"id":"myid","base":{"brands":["KI", "SA"],"country":"BG","status":"new"}},{"id":"DEC-00500331","base":{"brands":["DEC"],"country":"UK","status":"new"},"psp":{"name":"adyen","status":"paid"}}]
```

An order is related to a country website, and can contain one or more brands. for example in one order I can have and item from brand1 and an item from brand2.

I need to group these orders, by country and brand so I can have a consolidated array or object.

I can group by country easily :

```
let groupedDataByCountryAndBrand = _.groupBy(orders.value, 'base.country') 
Object.keys(groupedDataByCountryAndBrand).forEach(key => {
  table.push(
    {
      country : key, //to be reviewd : for the two brands or more in one order 
      new : groupedDataByCountryAndBrand[key].filter( order => (order.base.status === SFCC_STATUS.new
      || SFCC_STATUS.open
      || SFCC_STATUS.completed )).length
    })
})
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Unfortunatly this is not working for me. I need to group the orders by country and brand so that I can count the newly created orders for each brand by country.

Result I am expecting is something like this :

```
{
  "country" : "FR",
  "brand": "adidas",
  "pending": 4
  "new" : 3,
  "an other status": 5
}
```

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this ?

I am using lodash with vue component.
Thanks.

Comment: Adding your object as text and not an image will help people test their answers. You don't need to add the entire object, just relevant parts to give us an idea of the structure.

Comment: I just added a snippet of my object

Comment: Thanks, but your object is still quite large and looks like it includes irrelevant data that isn't needed for this question. It makes it difficult to look at the input and see how it maps/results in the output. It looks like just providing some simple sample data such as `[{country: "BG", "brands":["KI", "SA"], status: "new"}, {country: "UK", "brands":["DEC"], status: "new"}, ...]` is enough for what you're trying to ask. All other propertise such as  `marketPlaceOrderCode`, etc. adds noise to your question and makes it harder to clearly see what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for, without using of any additional libraries:

```
const data = [{"id":"myid","base":{"orderNumber":"0500332","marketPlaceOrderCode":"","creationDate":"2022-06-14T10:49:10Z","source":"sfcc","brands":["KI", "SA"],"country":"BG","status":"new","totalEuro":12,"currency":"BGN","units":1,"coupons":null,"shipping":{"id":"BG01","name":"Speedy COD","status":"not_shipped"}},"psp":{"name":"payu","method":null,"status":null},"tms":null},{"id":"DEC-00500331","base":{"orderNumber":"id2","marketPlaceOrderCode":"","creationDate":"2022-06-14T10:41:29Z","source":"sfcc","brands":["DEC"],"country":"UK","status":"new","totalEuro":57,"currency":"GBP","units":1,"coupons":null,"shipping":{"id":"ECA_DPD_ST","name":"Standard shipping","status":"not_shipped"}},"psp":{"name":"adyen","method":null,"status":"paid"},"tms":null}];

const rawResult = normalizeData(data);
console.log(makeItReadable(rawResult));

function normalizeData(data) {
  const result = {};

  data.forEach((order) => {
    const orderData = order.base;

    // add country to result (if not exists)
    if (!result[orderData.country]) {
      result[orderData.country] = {};
    }

    orderData.brands.forEach((brand) => {
      // add brand to exact country (if not exists)
      if (!result[orderData.country][brand]) {
        result[orderData.country][brand] = {};
      }

      // add status to exact brand and country (if not exists)
      if (!result[orderData.country][brand][orderData.status]) {
        result[orderData.country][brand][orderData.status] = 0;
      }

      // increment status count
      ++result[orderData.country][brand][orderData.status];
    });
  });

  return result;
}

function makeItReadable(rawData) {
  const readableResult = [];
  Object.keys(rawData).map((country) => {
    Object.keys(rawData[country]).map((brand) => {
      readableResult.push({country, brand, ...rawData[country][brand]});
    });
  });

  return readableResult;
}
```

This code will give you the following result:

```
[
  { country: 'BG', brand: 'KI', new: 1 },
  { country: 'BG', brand: 'SA', new: 1 },
  { country: 'UK', brand: 'DEC', new: 1 }
]
```